# jQuery change the width of a div based on the width of the closest image?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a ul that has the following structure:

```
<ul>
<li><img><div class="infotext">some variable length text</div></li>
<li><img><div class="infotext">some variable length text</div></li>
<li><img><div class="infotext">some variable length text</div></li>
<ul>
```

The images are being given a dynamic height based on the window height and their width is auto (and variable, my images have varying proportions but I am keeping them all the same height), and so I would like to make my infotext div match this variable width. I have tried the following:

```
jQuery('.infotext').width(jQuery(this).closest('img').width());

jQuery('.infotext').width(jQuery('.infotext').closest('img').width());

jQuery('.infotext').width(jQuery('.infotext').parent().width());
```

but none of them are working. So far I am stumped...

**UPDATE:**
I have figured out what is causing this, but not what the solution is yet. My images are using lazyloading, and that is interfering with getting the correct image height. I need to figure out how to get the image size after lazy loading has happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, what a mess (but a good learning opportunity). The problems turned out to be:

1. I was unable to get the width and height on these elements, possibly due to lazy loading them. I was able to pull the height alone since I was setting it based on window height.
2. Because the height and width would change based on the size of my window, and sizing was not set on the images prior, I was having a hard time getting the values I needed to make my calculations.

**Solution**

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is what I came up with and it works (finally):

First, I added original width and height as data attributes to each image like so:

```
<img src="lazyload.gif" data-original="path/to/my/originalfile.jpg" data-original-width="<?php echo $image_attributes["width"]; ?>" data-original-height="<?php echo $image_attributes["height"]; ?>" />
```

then in my jQuery I calculated based on the style being added to the images (depending on the height of the window) and compared that to the original height to get my formula to transform the original width:

```
jQuery('.infotext').each(function(){
    var newWidthCalc = (jQuery(this).prev('img').attr( "data-original-height" )/jQuery(this).prev('img').css("height").replace('px', ''));
    var newWidth = (jQuery(this).prev('img').attr( "data-original-width" )/newWidthCalc);
    newWidth = (parseInt(newWidth)-30) + 'px'; //remove 30 pixels so a little smaller
    jQuery(this).css('width',newWidth);
    }
});
```

And finally, it works!

Answer (score 1):

The image tag is the previous element, not an ancestor, so `.closest()` and `.parent()` won't work.

Try:

```
jQuery('.infotext').each(function(){
    $(this).width(jQuery(this).prev('img').width());
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fx3V5/)**

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this (like the parent one I tried before) results in a width of 0

Comment: Still a width of zero. I notice your fiddle sets an explicit width on the images, something my code does not have. Width is "auto", so that might be why this does not work for me?

Comment: There's no explicit width set either via CSS or the width attribute. Where do you see that?

Comment: oops you are right, that was in the fiddle below. But nevertheless, the code still returns "width:0" for me (although strange, that is in Safari; in FF it returns "width:1px;")

Comment: Are you running the jQuery with a document.ready or window.load? It's possible your code runs before the images have loaded.

Comment: I am running with document ready, but I also tried it with window.load and got same thing...

Comment: In your example code you have `<img>`. Are you loading the images dynamically or are they there when the page loads?

Comment: They are loading from a db query via php echo

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is used to look for parent elements. In this case you want `prev()`:

```
jQuery('.infotext').width(function() {
    return $(this).prev('img').width();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XCrtE/1/)

Comment: @Stephen I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean like the response just above it, this results in a width of 0

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Is the content being appended dynamically? Are you running your code after images have loaded? As you can see it works in a fiddle, so there must be another factor in your code affecting the logic.

Comment: see my response above, you have an explicit width on the images, I do not. I think that might be the problem...I have no console errors btw...

Comment: I tried moving this code after the code that resizes the images, it does give a different response, but oddly still does not get the correct width of the image...but I think we are on the right track...

Comment: actually, I take that back, I was wrong. It is not correct UNDER that dimension either. So I am back to square one :(